# HTTP GET request with null parameters retruning error 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, routes, request

when I use my GET request and the parameters is null the client don't find the address route and return a 404 error (Not Found). I am sure this is an obvius mistake and I am missing something trivial, can someone guide me please ?

I am using JS in front and node.js/Express.js in back with the library [routing-controllers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/routing-controllers)

Client

```
let searchValue = ''
result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/app/getRef/entitee/${searchValue}", {method:"GET"});
```

Server

```
@Get('/getRef/entitee/:searchValue')
async getRefEntitee(@Req() req: any, @Res() res: any, @Param("searchValue") searchValue : string}: Promise<any>  {

...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending a `null`, you're sending an empty string. The backend expects an argument at `getRef/entitee/:searchValue` but it is redirected to a route called `getRef/entitee/` which is totally different.

The solution is to change the backend to expect a query parameter and the frontend to send it like this:

```js
result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/app/getRef/entitee?q=${searchValue}", {method:"GET"});
```

This way it will work.

Comment: Thanks it works, I used query parameter in the frontend and changed the routing-controllers decorator in my backend (from Param to QueryParam)
`result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/app/getRef/entitee?searchValue=${searchValue}", {method:"GET"});
`

`@Get('/getRef/entitee/:searchValue')
async getRefEntitee(@Req() req: any, @Res() res: any, @QueryParam("searchValue") searchValue : string}: Promise<any>  {

...

}`

Comment: I also added a route to the controller   `@Get('/getRefSchema/entitee') @Get('/getRef/entitee/:searchValue')`

Answer (score 1):

when there is no value after last '/', since searchValue is blank string, belong route don't handle this request.

if there will be any route like /getRef/entitee, it handles this req
but there is no such route and your getting default 404 error

You can use query params